# Different results with different methods to same limit of polynomial

Tags: limits, exponentiation, radicals, limits-without-lhopital

I'm considering the following limit while looking for asymptotes:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \arctan\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x-1}$$

Going the route I initially tried, I divide both parts of the fraction by $x^4$ which would give $\arctan(\infty)$, or $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as the result.

But according to Wolfram, the solution is $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$, which you get by instead taking $x^2$ out of the square root in the numerator, then dividing both numerator and denominator by $x$ which gives $\arctan(1)$, or $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

My question is why my initial approach didn't yield the right result, and why it isn't allowed to do it like I did.

Comment: Are you trying to evaluate the limit or to find asympotes?

Comment: I don't see how, dividing numerator and denominator by $x^4$, you can obtain $\infty$ as a limit for the fraction.

Comment: @Bernard My logic being taking $x^4$ under the root would make it into $x^2$, and then I would have in the numerator $\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}} = \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}$. That would leave me with $\arctan\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}{\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^4}} = arctan(\infty)$

Comment: But if you divide the numerator by $x^4$, it takes $x^8$  under the root, not $x^2$.

Comment: I'm an utter dunce. I shouldn't practice math this late in the night. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rather *pull* $x^2$ from the square root:
$$
\sqrt{x^2+1}=\sqrt{x^2\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}
=x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}
$$
(because you can assume $x>0$ as you're evaluating the limit for $x\to\infty$).

Then you similarly pull $x$ from $x-1$ getting
$$
x\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$
then you get
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan\frac{\sqrt{1+1/x^2}}{1-1/x}=\arctan 1
$$
The method is not that different from yours, but you should beware that $x^4=x^{8/2}=\sqrt{x^8}$.